# Reducing 12 modulo 9

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This example is from a text on Modular Arithmetic

> We want to reduce `12 modulo 9`. Here are several results which are
> correct according to the definition:
>
> `1) 12 ≡ 3 mod 9`,     `3` is a valid remainder since `9|(12−3)`
> `2) 12 ≡ 21 mod 9`,    `21` is a valid remainder since `9|(21−3)`
> `3) 12 ≡ −6 mod 9`,    `−6` is a valid remainder since `9|(−6−3)`

I understand the first one.

For `a ≡ r mod m`, we can write `m | (a - r)`

So in the first example, `a = 12 r = 3 m = 9`.
So from that we get `9 | (12 - 3)`

But for the second, a similar substitution would be
`9 | (12 - 21)` - But in the example, they have `(21 - 3)` instead of `(12 - 21)`
Likewise in the $3^{rd}$, they have `(-6 -3)` instead of `(12 + 6)`

How do they arrive at this in the $2^{nd}$ & $3^{rd}$ example?

Comment: They are using example 1.

Comment: That seems like sloppy editing. They probably had $3\equiv12$, $3\equiv21$ and $3\equiv-6$ as the modular equations at first, but then swapped the 3 and 12 in order to talk about reduction rather than equivalence (which seems a bad idea to me), but then forgot to update the second parts. Note however that since it is an equivalence relation it still is true: if $p|(a-b)$ and $p|(b-c)$ then $p|(a-c)$ because $(a-c)=(a-b)+(b-c)$

Comment: @QiZhu `That are using example 1` - what are using example 1?

Comment: Sorry, I typo'd, I meant to say "They".

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - I don't understand - can you please elaborate? This is from the book "Understanding Cryptography" by Christof Paar

Comment: @QiZhu - I still don't get what you are saying

Comment: Mod ( n)  is an equivalence relation. So you can use transitivity and symmetry

Comment: @JaapScherphuis - I think you are correct. The author is trying to find the equivalence class rather than do reduction.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I think the author is trying to find all answers which form an equivalence class for `mod 9`.

3, 21 & -6 are all part of the equivalence class for `mod 9`.

{ ...-15, -6, 3, 12, 21, ... } is one of the 9 equivalence classes for `mod 9`.

That's how he gets to (2) & (3) from (1)

Answer (score 0):

If $a \equiv b \pmod m$ and $b \equiv c \pmod m$, then $a \equiv c \pmod m$. This is called transitivity and you should prove that it is true.

For your second example: The author in your text uses $12 \equiv 3 \pmod 9$ and $3 \equiv 21 \pmod 9$, so $$ 12 \equiv 3 \equiv 21 \pmod 9.$$ Of course, you can also just check $9 \mid 12 - 21$, as you said.

Comment: `For your second example: The author in your text uses 12≡3(mod9) and 3≡21(mod9),` - where did the 3≡21(mod9) come from? I know his end conclusion is correct but where did he get 3≡21(mod9) from?

Comment: I am a total beginner at Modular arithmetic - this is almost the first couple of pages I am reading - so nothing he has explained till now tells me how he came upon `3≡21(mod9)`

Comment: It comes from $9 \mid (21-3)$ as you have quoted in your second example. It just means that they leave the same remainder upon division by $9$.

Comment: Ok, got it. They should have written `9 | (21 - 3)` in the first half of the line & `12 ≡ 21 mod 9` in the 2nd half of the line. Writing it in the way they did, made me believe that the 2nd half comes from the first half. So what you are saying is that they found `( a - b )'s` which are divisible by 9 & then got the first half from that